# SwiftUI NavigationView Secondary not showing

Tags: swiftui, uisplitviewcontroller, navigationview

Using Xcode 12.4 running on the simulator using iOS 14.4

Running the following code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("some View")
                .navigationBarTitle("Primary View")
            
            Text("Secondary")
        }
    }
}
```

The following is rendered in Landscape:

[image]

I would was expecting to see ***"Secondary"*** with a ***Back Button*** in the ***top left corner*** to navigate back to the ***"some View"***. All of the YouTube videos I have seen behave in the manor I have just described.

Any clue as to why this isn't behaving as expected?

Comment: What size simulator is this running on?

Comment: Yes this is the correct question to ask! I was running it on a iPhone 12 and not a 12 Pro Max - What an idiot - I deserved the down vote! @jnpdx - thanks for taking a look and an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior on devices with a "compact width" size class.

On devices that report "regular width", you will see the split `NavigationView`.

You can see the table of device and size classes at: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/